# Controllino Debugging

Tags: debugging, atmega2560

Its a well known fact, that you can debug your arduino board with the help of an Atmel Ice. However, you might know the [Controllino](https://controllino.biz/controllino/maxi/) which is an arduino compatible device.

It has an ATmega2560 on it.

Do you have an idea how to debug a controllino? I neither see any ICSP port nor did I found anything useful around this topic.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Connector X1 has the pins you want.

ICSP is shared with the SPI pins. Wire those to your ICE in the same way as you wire the SPI pins of the ICSP header on a normal Arduino to an ICE.

Comment: Thx for the fast answer. Is there anything else I need to know before I can start debugging? I read about cutting the reset line when debugging arduinos...